# javascript reveal layers errors on certain browsers

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html

I just couldn't get the code to work on certain browsers, basically whatever code you see on the resource url below has all been work-around-codes to get this work mainly for android browsers and windows 8. So this may be a little sketchy.

Currently, this code below shows the page layers when the buttons are clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mouths9").click(function() {
        $("#mouth").toggle();
```

I either want it to when a user clicks anywhere (other than the selected #mouth/div) to close the toggled layer #mouth.

every show() commands I have tried, doesn't show the layers on android devices, so the toggle has been, so far anyway the only thing that has worked.

Surely there's a better way of doing this? if anyone wants to see how far I have gotten the resource url can be seen at http://a1jw.com/mker/newChoopie/testing/stage7/

Comment: is this your real code? Because you are missing closing braces (`}`) ?

Comment: this originally was not my code no - i have been trying to fix it up and rebuilding it. there is a major issue with it, so iv been having to add extra js now to correct what ever was wrong. No one on here helped with various questions so i have it to this stage myself.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").not("#mouths9").click(function(){
        $("#mouth").hide();
    });
    $("#mouths9").click(function() {
        $("#mouth").show();
    ));
}):
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight however this doesnt do the job either.you might not see it on desktop browser however the .toggle() way messes up the layers yet .show() always shows nothing. this is puzzling for sure.